# Jquery - How do you pass a variable into a function to use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scope

I am stumped by a problem which i'd assume is a common Jquery occurence, but i've no idea how to fix!

I have 5 variables -

```
 var pubtimed 
 var toolstimed 
 var newstimed 
 var mylinkstimed 
 var partnerstimed
```

Which are used to store on and off states.
I then have a script that checks cookies for recent states and updates the variables accordingly, then forwards the details onto a render function -

```
var map = {
    'pub': $.cookie('nwphportal_tabExpPub'),
    'tools': $.cookie('nwphportal_tabExpTools'),
    'news': $.cookie('nwphportal_tabExpNews'),
    'mylinks': $.cookie('nwphportal_tabExpLinks'),
    'partners': $.cookie('nwphportal_tabExpPartners')
}

$.each(map, function (key, value) {
    if (value != null) {
        var varname = key + 'timed';
        varname = value;
        renderScrn(varname)
    } else {
        var varname = key + 'timed';
        varname = "1"
        renderScrn(varname)
    }
});
```

The problem I have is that I want the variable varname to be treated as each of the 5 variables above (e.g. key plus timed = pubtimed).  But this doesnt happen and I just get an error.  I could just place a list of if statements to fix this, but wondered if there were a better solution?

Please help if you can!

Cheers for your time.
Paul

Comment: Please could you edit your post? If you select the code and hit the button that looks like binary code, it will format it so we can read it much better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they're global variables, you can do this:

```
window[key + 'timed'] = value;
```

If they're *not* global (though they look so from what you posted), then you'll have to keep them in a container object, kind-of like your "map":

```
var container = {
  pubtimed: null,
  // ...
};

// ...

    container[key + 'timed'] = value;
```

*edit* — as @galambalazs wrote in his answer, it'd be better to avoid doing this. If you set up a container, just use the keys directly.

Comment: +1 for correct answer to immediate problem. But it is also worth considering a cleaner approach.

Comment: Yes I agree, @Pekka; I wouldn't code it like that. Such is life on StackOverflow :-)  (I'll add to my answer.)

Answer (score 3):

I would go for namespacing, encapsulating the related data into one object:

```
var timed = {};

$.each(map, function (key, value) {

    if (value != null) {
        timed[key] = value;
        renderScrn(varname);
    }

    else {
        timed[key] = 1;
        renderScrn(varname);
    }
});​
```

So you can call them `timed.partners`, `timed.pub`, and so on...

Comment: cool cheers, both solutions work great.  thanks for your time

Comment: it's always the best too keep your global namespace clean and sparate your code.